# How to only return non-empty results for multi-part query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query with the following structure:

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE as varchar(30)
SET @VARIABLE = 'Thing to look up'

select * from ref.Table1 where columnX = @VARIABLE
select * from ref.Table2 where columnX2 = @VARIABLE
...
select * from ref.TableN where columnXn = @VARIABLE
```

I use it **to check many reference tables that all have different columns**, but use the same Identifier that I'm looking for with @VARIABLE.

There are 50+ tables I'm checking.  **I only want to return results when there is a match with @VARIABLE in that specific table.**

I'm not a developer, but I'm sure there is a more 'programmatic' way of doing this.  What is a more recommended way?

---

edit:

To be clear, my current query works in the SQL Server 2012 UI, where I do my day-to-day work.  I run the query, and I get about 50 tables returned.  Most have nothing matched, so I only see the header.  I would like to only return the tables where there is a match.

Comment: probably you need `UNION ALL`  Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: One question - do you need to know which table(s) the reference was found in, or only the fact that it was found? If you need the table information, you may want to hard code that as a return value in the rows.  As Juan Carlos Oropeza said, a UNION or UNION ALL is the way to go on this - UNION if you just want to know it exists, UNION ALL if you want to know how many times it exists.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Thank you.  However, as stated, the columns are different so this will not work.  I will re-read the how-to-ask.  Cheers

Comment: @LaughingVergil: I have actually included the following form: "" Select 'ref.tablex' as [ref.tablex], * from ref.tablex where... "" in each of my queries.  I just didn't want to confuse the question more.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: If the tables are different what result you expect? Instead of waste our time trying to guess what you need, rethink your problem and rewrite it in a way everyone can understand.

Comment: Ok saw the edit, you want an `IF EXISTS()` statement, see my answer edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems like this is an ad-hoc query that you run in some front end like query analyzer or visual studio.

You can use an if statement and if exists, like this:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from ref.Table1 where columnX = @VARIABLE)
  select * from ref.Table1 where columnX = @VARIABLE
;
```

To only run the query once to speed it up do this:

```
select * from ref.Table1 INTO #mytmp1 where columnX = @VARIABLE

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #mytmp1)
  SELECT * FROM #mytmp1
;
```

---

As @LaughingVergil points out you could have an issue if your id is not in the first table you can solve that like this:

```
select Table1.*, Table2.*, Table3.*, TableN.*
from (
   SELECT @VARIABLE as Criteria
) base
left join ref.Table1 where columnX = base.Criteria
left join ref.Table2 where columnX2 = base.Criteria
left join ref.Table3 where columnX3 =  base.Criteria
 -- ...
left join ref.TableN where columnXN =  base.Criteria
```

---

*to "discern" what table data is coming from*

```
select
  Table1.Field1 as Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2 as Table1.Field2,  -- etc
  Table2.Field1 as Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2 as Table2.Field2,  -- etc
  Table3.Field1 as Table3.Field1, Table3.Field2 as Table3.Field2,  -- etc
  TableN.Field1 as TableN.Field1, TableN.Field2 as TableN.Field2  -- etc
from (
   SELECT @VARIABLE as Criteria
) base
left join ref.Table1 where columnX = base.Criteria
left join ref.Table2 where columnX2 = base.Criteria
left join ref.Table3 where columnX3 =  base.Criteria
 -- ...
left join ref.TableN where columnXN =  base.Criteria
```

---

*original answer*

Typically in SQL we use JOINs for this kind of situation (you will probably need to be more specific about columns unless you don't care about multiple columns with the same name)

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE as varchar(30)
SET @VARIABLE = 'Thing to look up'

select Table1.*, Table2.*, Table3.*, TableN.*
from ref.Table1 
left join ref.Table2 where columnX2 = columnX
left join ref.Table3 where columnX3 = columnX
 -- ...
left join ref.TableN where columnXN = columnX
where columnX = @VARIABLE
```

Often a view is used to make it easier (here you have to be specific about column names or the create view will fail).

```
create view myview as 
select Table1.*, Table2.*, Table3.*, TableN.*
from ref.Table1 
left join ref.Table2 where columnX2 = columnX
left join ref.Table3 where columnX3 = columnX
 -- ...
left join ref.TableN where columnXN = columnX
```

then

```
select *
from myview
where columnX = @VARIABLE
```

Comment: You have an unwarranted assumption that the item being looked for must be found in Table1. The structure WHERE columnx = @VARIABLE requires the item to be found in Table1. Also, this form of SELECT can blow up badly. You are adding all columns in one row, yet SQL Server has a data length limit per row. A UNION [ALL] is the correct way to do this type of query.

Comment: @LaughingVergil -- union will fail if there are different columns in each table.  There usually are -- unless the user made a horrible design choice.  see edit for solution to the issue you raise.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. It depends on the definition of the tables, and what is being looked up. For example, I have seen a number of systems where multiple divisions or "companies" are split up into multiple identical databases. If the user question is looking for a customer that may exist in another division for the purposes of data sharing, then the columns would most likely be identical. We don't have enough information to say. There is also the related problem of possible duplicate column names in multi-table, one row format that can confound a program reading the data.

Comment: I would re-iterate a point from my original posting: The columns in each reference table are very different and messy.

To your other recommendation, joining won't work because I don't want one row and many hundreds of columns where it's hard to discern from which table I'm looking.

Comment: My query is frankly very workable right now.  I just don't want to see all the empty table returns in cases where there is not a match on any given table.

Comment: @ColinMac -- I'm missing something -- what exactly do you mean by " don't want to see all the empty table returns" -- what exactly are you seeing.  I don't understand context here, it sounds like this is a UI issue.

Comment: @ColinMac -- I wrote an example about how to make it easy to "discern" where data is coming from.

Comment: @LaughingVergil -- just because you have seen an example of it does not make it a good design -- if you are doing a UNION a lot in that design it was probably a mistake.  However, your point that UNIONS exist is reasonable, they do.  Just not for this question.

Comment: @Hogan.  That's a good point -- I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Hogan.  Thanks -- The "IF EXISTS ( ...)" clause solved my problem... It would be nice though if it was faster.  As it works now, I have about a hundred lines of SQL. For each of my "stacked" queries (in the sense that I run all of these "if exists() then [run original]" one after another... it runs the query twice...  I will probably ask a new question.

Comment: @ColinMac it will run your query twice.  You could use temporary tables to speed it up.  I'll post an example.

Comment: @Hogan - I made a new question.  Perhaps you can answer that one as it is more specific to this follow-up question that I asked in the comments here.

Comment: @Hogan - also, the joins are not appropriate here because I am reading the results of the query in the SQL Server 2012 RDBMS... many of the ref tables have a hundred columns... it would be very difficult to read so many joined tables.

Comment: @ColinMac - I believe we covered the joins 4 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Your basic query form should be - If you want the tables the reference is in:

```
SELECT 'Table1', * FROM Table1 WHERE columnx = @VARIABLE
UNION
SELECT 'Table2', * FROM Table2 WHERE columnx2 = @VARIABLE
UNION ...
SELECT 'TableN', * FROM TableN WHERE columnxN = @VARIABLE
```

If you want to know whether it exists in any of the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE columnX = @VARIABLE
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE columnX2 = @VARIABLE
UNION ...
SELECT * FROM TableN WHERE columnXN = @VARIABLE
```

NOTE: `UNION` will de-duplicate rows. If you want to include duplicate rows, then change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`